# How to sum up all values in a listbox column and display it in a textblock?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

**How do I got about summing up the amount in the red box and display it in the textblock (yellow box)?**

[image]

**As you can see from the image below, I have bind my observable collection to the Listbox in order to display the data in the listbox**

[image: Listbox]

**In addition, I have also defined the data template for the listbox.**

[image]

Comment: FYI, you can use the `code` tool when you want to use blocks of markup/code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another property (e.g. `Sum`) into your ViewModel, bind it into your `TextBlock` and calculate it's value every time `ToDoBills` collection changes.

You can use LINQ to calculate the sum:

```
Sum = ToDoBills.Sum(i => i.Amount);
```

*Update*

You probably already implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `ViewModel` class, so use it to update `Sum` property value when collection is changed:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    if(propertyName == "ToDoBills")
        UpdateSumValue();
}

private void UpdateSumValue()
{
     Sum = ToDoBills.Sum(i => i.Amount);
}
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to create another observable collection property and another table in my data context to store the sum? =o

Comment: Hmm how come there is red underline under my Sum? Am I missing something? Btw what is a caller member name?

Comment: `CallerMemberName` is not important here. `Sum` is name of your new property, which you should create to store sum value.

Comment: After creating the observable collection property for sum I get the error which says cannot impliciyly convert type 'double' to System.collections.obectModel.observablecollection<ToDoBill>

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask that question: do you have any idea what you're doing?

Comment: Sry I'm still new to MVVM and windows phone development. That's why I'm not sure on how to go about implementing.